# D3 Typescript error when using d3.mouse: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I am using `d3` in my react application, where I write code using Typescript. I have the following code:

```
function mousemove() {
        // recover coordinate we need
        var x0 = xScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]);
        var i = bisect(data, x0, 1);
        var selectedData = data[i]
        focus
            .attr("cx", xScale(selectedData.dateCreated))
            .attr("cy", yScale(selectedData[value]))
        focusText
            .html("x:" + selectedData.x + "  -  " + "y:" + selectedData.y)
            .attr("x", xScale(selectedData.dateCreated) + 15)
            .attr("y", yScale(selectedData[value]))
}
```

`d3.mouse(this)[0]` throws the following error:

> 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.

Any suggestions to resolve it? This error is common typescript but I do not how to resolve it with `d3.mouse` function.

Comment: Closely related and, probably, a better solution: [*"D3, Typescript - Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BaseType'"*](/q/53855394).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that this is a custom method passed to the d3.js's event handler (i.e `.on('mousemove')`)

Instead of referencing `this`, which might be inferred as an instance of your current class, you can handle the event callback by referencing the actual event handler.

```
.on('mousemove' (d, i) => {
  mousemove();
})

function mousemove() {
  const x0 = xScale.invert(d3.mouse(d3.event.currentTarget));
  // do the rest
}
```

Alternatively, you may pass the node to your `mousemove()` function. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_select),

> If the selector is a function, it is evaluated for each selected
>   element, in order, being passed the current datum (d), the current
>   index (i), and the current group (nodes), with this as the current DOM
>   element (nodes[i]).

```
.on('mousemove' (d, i, n) => {
  const node = d[i]
  mousemove(node);
})

function mousemove(node) {
      // do the rest
}
```